# How to get document from "Firestore" using compound query in android

Tags: android, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I have Constructed a firebase query like this for all my dropdown spinners in app.

Actually i have more than 20 spinners in my android app to search users from firebase firestore collection based on any dropdown selected. currently i handled all possible scenario by using if else condition and make compound query base on any selected spinner. but this is not a good approach which i am currently using. i need to append query next to any query without handle any spinner check..her is my code.

```
Query query;
CollectionReference collection = 
firestore.collection(Constants.MEMBERS);
query  = collection;

if (rangeBarRating.getRightIndex() != 0 && spinnerReligion.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
        query =  collection.whereEqualTo(Constants.RELIGION,spinnerReligion.getSelectedItem()).whereEqualTo(Constants.REGISTERATION_STATUS,rangeBarRating.getRightIndex());
    } else if (spinnerCountry.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
        query =  collection.whereEqualTo(Constants.COUNTRY_LIVING_IN,spinnerCountry.getSelectedItem());
    }else if (rangeBarRating.getRightIndex() != 0){
        query =  collection.whereEqualTo(Constants.REGISTERATION_STATUS,rangeBarRating.getRightIndex());
    }else if ((rangeBarAge.getLeftIndex()+18) > 18){
        query =  collection.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(Constants.AGE,(rangeBarAge.getLeftIndex()+18));
    }
```

I need dynamically approach like i only use if statement not if else . if some spinner is selected then append that spinner value in my query and get desired result.

Comment: So you want something like wildcards?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "append query next to any query".  Are you trying to apply multiple filters to your query?

Comment: @AlexMamo i dont know what is wildcard in Firebase .. brother actually i want something like this
`if( spinner one is selected)
query =  collection.whereEqualTo(Constants.RELIGION,spinnerReligion.getSelectedItem());
 if(spinner 2 is selected then){
something like this
query = collection.append next where clause to collection}`

Comment: @DougStevenson yes brother exactly . i need to apply multiple filters for search in my collection.. i have 25+ spinners in my app ..user can select any spinner what he want to search or he can select multiple spinners according to his search criteria

Comment: @YasirAli So you have a based query and according to the data selected in the spinner you want to add more `whereEqualTo` calls to your query, am I understanding right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes brother you get it. how can i do this? currently i implement if else check like
`if(spinner a is selected && spinner b is selected && spinner c is selected){
  then perform query using whreEqualto().whereEqualTo()
}else if(spiiner a is selected and spiiner c is selected){
then again sperate query
}`
this approach takes too much time for 25+ spinners ..its about 300+ if else conditions

Comment: Right now you are only applying one filter at time, but it seems to me that you already understand how to chain your filters.  So I'm not very certain what sort of solution you need that you don't already know how to write.

Comment: @DougStevenson so whats your opinion ? should i use if else condition to handle every single filter or is there any other technique to add more `whereEqualTo` calls to my query?

Comment: I would say do whatever works.  Stack Overflow isn't really a place to ask for opinions.  Either it works or it doesn't work.  If it works, then everything is good.

Comment: @YasirAli Agree with Doug. So you should make your own attempt to chain multiple method calls and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your support.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake in how you assign the conditional query. You want each condition to be added to the existing query, but are in fact constantly rebuilding a new query from the collection. To fix this, build from `query` every time you add a condition:

```
firestore.collection(Constants.MEMBERS);
query = collection;

if (rangeBarRating.getRightIndex() != 0 && spinnerReligion.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
    query =  query.whereEqualTo(Constants.RELIGION,spinnerReligion.getSelectedItem()).whereEqualTo(Constants.REGISTERATION_STATUS,rangeBarRating.getRightIndex());
} else if (spinnerCountry.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
    query =  query.whereEqualTo(Constants.COUNTRY_LIVING_IN,spinnerCountry.getSelectedItem());
}else if (rangeBarRating.getRightIndex() != 0){
    query =  query.whereEqualTo(Constants.REGISTERATION_STATUS,rangeBarRating.getRightIndex());
}else if ((rangeBarAge.getLeftIndex()+18) > 18){
    query =  query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(Constants.AGE,(rangeBarAge.getLeftIndex()+18));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Puff, this is exactly what i want. you save a lot of my time and extra if else check..